# How do I fill out a form using Protractor and TextAngular?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, textangular

I am trying to submit a form which uses TextAngular for some of the input fields.

I can't seem to find anything about populating these fields - the closest I have come is [this](https://gist.github.com/CollDoc/5b665ddc4ffdd9410cee), but if I try something similar I get an error that Element is not clickable at point (240, 249). Other element would receive the click.

**Edit:**

*Finally* got the following to work, but given the lack of search results I am assuming there is a more straight forward way...

```
element(by.model('activity.description')).element(by.css('.ta-bind')).click();
browser.actions().sendKeys(data.description).perform();
```

Comment: Do you get any error if you use - `element(by.model('commentary.content')).sendKeys('Prueba comentario');` without clicking on it?

Comment: @GirishSortur Failed: unknown error: cannot focus element.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this as a normal input

```
var taInput  = browser.element(by.model('formData.description')).$('div.ta-bind');
taInput.sendKeys('your text');
expect(taInput.getText()).toEqual('your text');
```

If you want to work with html, you can use this instead

```
browser.element(by.model('formData.description')).$('textarea.ta-bind');
```